# multiplying a variable using user input

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string visitorname;

    cout << "Hello, welcome to Montgomery College! My name is Nao. May I have your name? \n";
    getline(cin, visitorname);
    cout << "Nice to meet you" << visitorname << "\n";
    cout << "Let me impress you with a small game.\n";
    cout << "Give me the age of an important person or a pet to you.\n Please give me only a number";

    int Age;
    int month;
    int days;
    days = 30 * month;

    cin >> Age;
    cout << "You have entered " << Age;
    cout << "If this is for a person, the age can be expressed as " << Age << "years";
    month = Age * 12;

    cout << "or" << month;
    cout << "or" << days;

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting an error for `Age`. `Age` needs to be inputted by the user and then used for the other variables.

Comment: _"I keep getting an error"_  Please, share the error you are getting.  They usually describe the problem that needs to be remedied.

Comment: Perhaps related:  What _exact number_ do you expect `30 * month` to produce?  What value does `month` have?

Comment: No response, but I think the issue here is in learning that C++ code is (perceptibly) executed **in order**, top to bottom.  They are like instructions in a recipe -- you don't jump around.

Comment: Hello Drew Dormann the error that I keep getting is C4700 uninitialized local variable 'Age' used

Answer (score 0):

In the expression `days = 30 * month`, `month` has not been assigned a value yet, so the result is *indeterminate*.  In C++, variables are not macros, so you can't assign an expression to a variable and then have it evaluated at a later time (there are ways to do that, but what you have is not one of them).

You seem to think that by assigning expressions to `month` and `days`, that assigning a value to `Age` afterwards will automatically update the values of `month` and `days`.  That is simply not true.  Variables are initialized (or not) at the point where they are declared, and are evaluated at the point where they are referred to, in the order that instructions are written.

So, you need to first read in `Age`, THEN you can use its value to calculate `month`, which can THEN be used to calculate the value of `days` (which BTW, not all months have 30 days in them), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string visitorname;

    cout << "Hello, welcome to Montgomery College! My name is Nao. May I have your name?\n";
    getline(cin, visitorname);
    cout << "Nice to meet you" << visitorname << "\n";
    cout << "Let me impress you with a small game.\n";
    cout << "Give me the age of an important person or a pet to you.\nPlease give me only a number: ";

    int Age;
    int months;
    int days;

    cin >> Age;
    cout << "You have entered " << Age << "\n";
    cout << "If this is for a person, the age can be expressed as " << Age << " years";

    months = Age * 12;
    days = 30 * months;

    cout << " or " << months << " months";
    cout << " or " << days << " days";

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/DLFfOH)